# Wordpress / WooCommerce - Related Products by Attribute

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, related-posts

I know I'm not the first and I probably won't be the last to try to make this journey work. I've looked at everything that's out there.

Most answers are pre WC 2.1.

A lot of the replies work with the tax_query. Every once in a while, someone tries to touch the query. I've tried both, neither option works for me.

**How do I adjust the Related Products shown in WooCommerce to include relationships via Custom Attributes?**

**Goal**: Relationship via Cat AND (Brand OR Artist OR Manufacturer)

Test via `woocommerce_product_related_posts_query`:

```
function product_related_posts_relate_by_attributes ( $query ){
    global $product;

    //*
    $brands_array        = wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, 'pa_brand', array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
    $artists_array       = wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, 'pa_artist', array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );   
    $manufacturers_array = wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, 'pa_manufacturer', array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );

    $query['where'] .= ' AND (';        
        $query['where'] .= " ( tt.taxonomy = 'pa_brand' AND t.term_id IN ( " . implode( ',', $brands_array ) . " ) ) ";     
        $query['where'] .= ' OR ';  
        $query['where'] .= " ( tt.taxonomy = 'pa_artist' AND t.term_id IN ( " . implode( ',', $artists_array ) . " ) ) ";       
        $query['where'] .= ' OR ';  
        $query['where'] .= " ( tt.taxonomy = 'pa_manufacturer' AND t.term_id IN  ( " . implode( ',', $manufacturers_array ) . " ) ) ";      
    $query['where'] .= ')';//*/

    return $query;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_product_related_posts_query', 'product_related_posts_relate_by_attributes');
```

Test via `woocommerce_related_products_args`:

```
function custom_related_product_args ( $args ){
    global $product;

    $cats          = wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, 'product_cat', array( 'fields' => 'slug' ) );
    $brands        = wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, 'pa_brand', array( 'fields' => 'slug' ) );
    $artists       = wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, 'pa_artist', array( 'fields' => 'slug' ) );    
    $manufacturers = wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, 'pa_manufacturer', array( 'fields' => 'slug' ) );

    unset( $args['post__in'] );
    $args['tax_query'] = array( 
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $cats,
        ),
        array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'pa_brand',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => $brands,
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'pa_artist',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => $artists,
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'pa_manufacturer',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => $manufacturers,
            )
        )
    );

    return $args;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_related_products_args', 'custom_related_product_args');
```

Could someone please be so gracious as to tell me where I'm going wrong?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I tried the "test via woocommerce_related_products_args" and it appears you should just change the **'slug'** to **'slugs'** and also **'category'** to **'product_cat'** :)

```
global $product;

$cats          = wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, 'product_cat', array( 'fields' => 'slugs' ) );
$brands        = wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, 'pa_brand', array( 'fields' => 'slugs' ) );
$artists       = wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, 'pa_artist', array( 'fields' => 'slugs' ) );    
$manufacturers = wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, 'pa_manufacturer', array( 'fields' => 'slugs' ) );

unset( $args['post__in'] );
$args['tax_query'] = array( 
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => $cats,
    ),
    array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'pa_brand',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $brands,
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'pa_artist',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $artists,
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'pa_manufacturer',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $manufacturers,
        )
    )
);

return $args;
```